# struct messed up when passed as argument

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
void Test(struct NeuralNetwork *nn) {
     printf("%f", nn->layers[1].neurons[0].internalValue);
}
```

Later:

```
int inputs = 2;
int hiddenLayers = 3;
int outputs = 1;

struct NeuralNetwork* nn = NeuralNetwork( inputs, hiddenLayers, outputs);

printf("%f", nn->layers[1].neurons[0].internalValue); // prints correctly

Test(&nn); //access violation even tho im trying same print as above
```

printf prints 9.0 which is what i initialized it to in "NeuralNetwork()" function which returns a pointer NeuralNetwork*, so it works correctly.

When i call Test i get a read access violation error for trying to read  internalValue (0x9999999A).

In the NeuralNetwork function (constructor basically) i also do

```
nn->layers[1].neurons[0].internalValue = 9;
```

right before "return nn;" which is also what the printf prints.

I am able to access and edit all the values in the NeuralNetwork() function (which allocates memory and initializes all values then returns NeuralNetwork*) and i can also edit and read nn's data (as displayed by printf) which is assigned from NeuralNetwork()'s return.

I only get problems when i pass it to functions.

Comment: In the "later" part, what is the type of `nn`? And what is the type of `&nn`? The compiler should shout at you, don't disregard what the compiler tells you.

Comment: type is "struct NeuralNetwork*". struct NeuralNetwork consists of an array of layers, which contain an array of neurons. Neurons have a double internalValue, which i am able to read and write unless i pass it to the Test function which says i cant for some reason. All values are initialized in NeuralNetwork() function which returns a NeuralNetwork* which i then assign nn to.

Comment: Yes, the type of `nn` is `struct NeuralNetwork *`. Which means that the type of `&nn` is `struct NeuralNetwork **`. Now, what is the type of the argument that your `Test` function accepts? Should you really use the address-of operator `&` in the call?

Comment: Test function which accepts NeuralNetwork* isnt complaining, you have it in the post

Comment: If the compiler doesn't complain about the mismatch in the passed type and the function argument type, then either you haven't declared the function correctly or you have a seriously flawed compiler. A `struct NeuralNetwork *` is ***not*** the same as a `struct NeuralNetwork **`.

Comment: btw if you downvoted the post, why? Whats wrong with the question? You have all the types and the "Test" functions definition in the post, other stuff is way too long to include, and i believe i shown what the problem is without having to show the other stuff

Comment: Was a pretty simple to fix I guess. Maybe that's why? (as for me I didn't downvote)

Comment: For future questions please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And of course please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is rather important. And for possible reasons for downvotes, please read all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/. Lastly, and to not have problems like this again, I suggest you find a good text-book and repeat the chapters on pointers.

Comment: This is a viable minimal code demo that displays that despite initializing the values and being able to read and write, i only cant access from functions. It also has a worded description of that and some clarifications. I cant include the whole structure of the NeuralNetwork struct or the NeuralNetwork() function because of their lenght. But from the demo code its pretty clear that they dont matter as they work everywhere else but in the Test function

Comment: You claim that the compiler doesn't give you an error, but the call to `Test` *should* give you an error. That means the code isn't verifiable, and far from complete. For the code to be complete and verifiable, it should be possible for us to copy-paste it (without any modifications or changes) and get the same result you get. With your current code it's impossible. Now for this question it's still possible to deduce the problem, but ***you shouldn't have this problem to begin with*** since the compiler wouldn't allow it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing with this line:

```
Test(&nn);
```

is to call `Test` (which takes a pointer to `struct NeuralNetwork`) with a pointer to pointer to `struct NeuralNetwork`.
Usually, the compiler will emit an error/warning which will look something like this:

```
 error: cannot convert NeuralNetwork **' to NeuralNetwork *'.
```

So you end up accessing something you are not supposed to in the `Test` function.

Just call `Test` like this:

```
Test(nn);
```

Comment: Yay works now. I thought & was used to pass pointers into functions (it gives an address) which i guess makes sense that it gives an address of the pointer itself which is a double pointer (**). Fairly new to C :P

Comment: @LukaKostic: Welcome to the C programming community and happy learning.